# Reading 16bit matrox imaging library with emgu

Tags: c#, opencv, emgucv

I am trying to view in a pictureBox a tif raw file uncompressed. that was generated with 
"matrox imaging library"
I am using emgu.cv

I am doing:

```
Image<Gray, ushort> My_Image = new Image<Gray, ushort>(imgN);
Image<Gray, byte> My_Image1 = new Image<Gray, byte>(imgN);
```

and slso:

```
Image<Gray, byte> My_Image3 = My_Image.Convert<Gray, byte>();
```

I keep seeing black image,
any solutions?
I have also tried more combination  resulting in black ...

Comment: any details about parameters of the tif file? pixel depth, resolution etc?

Comment: with opencv you might be able to capture directly with ooencv: "The function cvCaptureFromCAM allocates and initializes the CvCapture structure for reading a video stream from the camera. Currently two camera interfaces can be used on Windows: Video for Windows (VFW) and Matrox Imaging Library (MIL);" from http://opencv.jp/opencv-2svn_org/c/highgui_reading_and_writing_images_and_video.html#capturefromcam

Comment: @Micka pix 1024X872 72X72 DPI

Comment: @Micka I am trying to read a file on my disk.

Comment: IrfanView is displaying the img correctly, in the details it points out that "original BBP was 16" and current colors are 256 8bpp

Comment: where do you diplay image to picturebox? can you show how you do that?

Comment: because for `Image<Bgr, Byte>` type image, i successfully had been `Querying` frame, displaing and updating in picturebox. what problem do you face? or i'm not getting your problem

Comment: according to http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/introduction/display_image/display_image.html#explanation openCV can read tif/tiff files. Can you read and display it with opencv (since your question is tagged opencv)? After reading with opencv, the image has 24 bit BGR format (if not loaded with original depth/channels explicitly), maybe that helps you working with your picture boxes (I dont know anything about picture boxes). If your image has alpha channels you'll have to take care while loading with openCV though.

Comment: @Zeeshan my problem is that the image display is "black" I dont see the gray level details IrfanView  sees.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked for me:

```
IntPtr img = CvInvoke.cvLoadImage(imgN,Emgu.CV.CvEnum.LOAD_IMAGE_TYPE.CV_LOAD_IMAGE_UNCHANGED);
MIplImage iplImage = (MIplImage)Marshal.PtrToStructure(img, typeof(MIplImage));

Image<Gray, UInt16> res;
res = new Image<Gray, UInt16>(1024, 872, iplImage.widthStep, iplImage.imageData);
imageBox1.Image = res;
```

using `imageBox1`